# Are there any conferences we should be going to?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Are there any Jewish conferences Judaism.SE should consider sponsoring and sending a representative to?

Conferences bring together high concentrations of highly interested people, and would give us a chance to promote the site face-to-face. In addition, a representative we send to a conference may learn some interesting information that could be useful in answering advanced questions on [main]. Stack Exchange, Inc. [has money available](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/) to do stuff like sponsor a conference, print up materials to bring, etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

How about reaching out to [Federation](http://www.jewishfederations.org/) to see if you can present @ the [GA](http://www.generalassembly.org/)?

Comment: Last year I believe there was a panel on social media.

Comment: Know anyone who was there?

Comment: I think I do. I'll ask around. Want me to put them in touch with you?

Comment: Yes, please. And also tell them to try out J.SE!

Answer (score 2):

Here are two Jewish journalism conferences that happened recently. Perhaps we could catch up with them next year.

- [American Jewish Press Association](http://www.cvent.com/events/2011-ajpa-annual-conference-june-27-30-2011/event-summary-82f5088e161d4a24b2efa4dfbed317ae.aspx)
- [National Jewish Student Journalism Conference](http://www.newvoices.org/pages?id=0016)

The next [Limmud Conference](http://www.limmud.org/conference/) in the UK will be December 23 - 29, 2011.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.youthcon.org/ - a conference for Jewish Youth Professionals, who would likely join and be active participants of the site.

http://www.fojnp.com/ - a conference for those who work in the Jewish non-profit field, again lots of people who would likely be actively involved in building the site.

**Full Disclosure:** Friends of mine are running both of these conferences.

Comment: Thanks! YouthCon looks particularly relevant. Both of these are coming up in 3-4 weeks. Do you know if there's any potential to add someone speaking about crowdsourced Jewish Q&A to, e.g., one of the Digital Media sessions at YouthCon at this late date? Could you please either email me at info@yodeya.com or join me in [chat] to discuss these ideas further?

Answer (score 2):

I just came across an ad for [TribeFest](http://www.tribefest.org/), a Federation conference for North American Jews ages 22-45.

There's information about being part of the vendor exhibition in [this PDF](http://www.tribefest.org/about-us/faq#how-can-i-be-an-exhibitor-in-the-big-show).

This year's conference is March 25 - 27, 2012, in Las Vegas.