# Would you like to represent Judaism.SE at an awesome-looking conference?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

We were recently [alerted](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278/are-there-any-conferences-we-should-be-going-to/313#313) to the existence of [YouthCon](http://www.youthcon.org/) 2011, "the first annual Informal Jewish Educators Convention." This site is all about informal Jewish education, and our work seems to fit in very well with other topics that will be [discussed](http://www.youthcon.org/schedule.html) there. The lineup looks quite interesting to me, as I expect it would to many Judaism.SE community members.

Consequently, we're considering sponsoring the convention and setting up an exhibition booth with a laptop on which passers-by can try out Judaism.SE. If we do this, we'll have passes for up to six representatives to attend the conference. If we get sufficient volunteers for this delegation, we'll apply to StackExchange for the funds necessary to sponsor the conference, pay our expenses for promotional materials, and possibly provide travel expenses for one or more representatives.

Would you possibly be interested in attending YouthCon on Judaism.SE's behalf? The conference is in Stamford, CT, on Sunday, August 21, 2011, all day. Anyone who attends as our representative would be expected to help staff the exhibition booth at least part of the day and probably to wear a sticker promoting this site all day, but would be free to attend conference sessions and the provided lunch any time they're not needed at the booth.

If you're possibly interested, please let us know as soon as possible either by posting an answer here or by emailing me at info@yodeya.com. If this is going to happen, we need to know very soon if anyone's a serious possibility, so we can apply for funds and make other arrangements.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that we got moving on this too close to the date of the conference. We need to identify future conferences a few months in advance and start early on getting people, money, and other resources lined up.

Comment: That is a shame. Wish I could have helped.

Comment: @WAF It's just a consequence of not getting into gear until too late. We'll be a well-tuned conference-delegating machine by the time it comes around next year.

Comment: That really is a shame. I was just about to ask how it went, actually. I call dibs on next year's YouthCon!

Comment: @Seth How about the GA and the associated Jewish Futures conference?