# Could a Mi-Yodeya-based high school class curriculum work?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I have thought for a [long time](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1011/2) that Mi Yodeya is potentially a particularly good place on the Internet for Jewish teens to hang out. Something I've also thought for a while but until now haven't posted here, is that it seems that it should be possible to come up with a valuable class curriculum (or unit curriculum) based around participation on Mi Yodeya.

Examples:

- In a Torah class, a unit on how to ask good questions, research well-sourced answers, etc.
- In a computer class, a unit on how to interact online in an environment that expects nice things like well-formed sentences and civility.
- In a writing class, a unit on writing good, concise, link-enhanced prose for the Internet.

It seems to me that a class unit along these lines could offer a special fusion of Torah thinking, writing, derech eretz, and Internet behavior that would be quite valuable to high school students in a Jewish school (or even in a Jewish informal educational program).

I don't know anything about writing curricula, but I know that there are educators on Mi Yodeya, and even more educators who are friends of people on Mi Yodeya. Would you be interested in trying your hand at creating something like this?

---

By the way:

- I have some ideas about this and a decent amount of experience with moderating and thinking about Mi Yodeya, and I'd be happy to collaborate.
- I have previously [suggested](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321/would-you-like-to-represent-judaism-se-at-an-awesome-looking-conference) that [YouthCon](http://www.youthcon.org/) would be an ideal conference to promote Mi Yodeya at. I stand by that, irrespective of this idea, but a curriculum like this would probably make for an excellent thing to present at that conference.

Comment: Homework for tonight: answer 5 questions with 5 different tags. Seems like something I would like :)

Comment: I can see some use in Judaic classes, requiring students pick a question and collect sources (if an answer has been written) or find sources and create an answer if it hasn't been. I will pass this along to the IT guy at my school.