# Let's create a logo graphic

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, design

If we end up sponsoring any [conferences](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278/are-there-any-conferences-we-should-be-going-to/) (and it's looking increasingly likely that we could be doing this very [soon](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321/would-you-like-to-represent-judaism-se-at-an-awesome-looking-conference)), we'll need a logo that conference organizers can put into their materials on our behalf.

Specifications:

- I don't know how large the image ought to be, but I guess it should be at a resolution that would look good anywhere in the one-inch to six-inch range.
- The image probably should include our site's current [icon](http://sstatic.net/judaism/img/apple-touch-icon.png). The [header graphic](http://cdn.sstatic.net/judaism/img/logo.png) is available as well.

  [icon http://sstatic.net/judaism/img/apple-touch-icon.png](http://sstatic.net/judaism/img/apple-touch-icon.png) [header graphic http://cdn.sstatic.net/judaism/img/logo.png](http://cdn.sstatic.net/judaism/img/logo.png)
- The image must include the judaism.stackexchange.com URL.

Comment: "The image must include the judaism.stackexchange.com URL" or mi.yodeya.com?

Comment: @msh210 Since this would be an expression of the site's official sponsorship of an event, I think we might as well stick to its official name. What do you think?

Comment: P'raps so. All right.

Comment: SEI has a professional designer, Jin, on staff for just this type of thing... Though it is a good idea to start gathering ideas, like this. Can I suggest, though, instead of asking for a design, ask for *ideas* for a design/theme?

Comment: @AviD I don't think Jin is going to make us anything until we get out of beta. We need to do promotional activities to get more people in so we can get out of beta. To that end, we need a basic logo, based on our current Sketchy theme, including the URL. Nothing fancy.

Comment: should we change that logo now?